# How do I install both Oracle 64-bit and 32-bit ODBC drivers and have both working in ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: microsoft-excel, drivers, oracle-database

**PREFACE:**
I am a novice when it comes to oracle and installing odbc drivers.

**SETUP:**
Laptop - Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit
Excel - 64-bit version
Application - 32-bit
Oracle instantclient_18_5

**PROBLEM**
An application I use very frequently uses the Oracle 32-bit ODBC drivers to read and write to oracle databases, however, I need the 64-bit Oracle ODBC Drivers to allow Excel to query the same/other oracle tables.

Is there any way to install the 64-bit and 32-bit Oracle ODBC drivers?

I have tried but it is acting as if the ODBC drivers for the 64-bit version is already installed but the ODBC Data Source Administrator can only see the 32-bit drivers.

I have found the following response on stackoverflow but I do not know how to do this on the updated versions of Oracle:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: I have looked through all of the crap on how to install them side-by-side.. I bet it still works but.. The easiest solution?  Uninstall office and re-install the 32bit version.  32bit is STILL the default office install for this and many other reasons.

Comment: You cannot use the 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit version of Excel.   You also cannot have a 32-bit and 64-bit version of the same version of Excel on the same system.  You can have a 32-bit ODBC driver installed on a 64-bit operating system.  It should be as simply as installing the 32-bit and the 64-bit driver, in my past experiences, it was that simple at least.

Comment: As @Ramhound said, you cannot use the 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit version of Excel. It's by design. You can't break this limit.

Comment: @Ramhound and Herb Gu - I do understand that you cannot use the 32-bit drivers with excel. Thats why I am curious as to how to properly install Oracle ODBC drivers for 64-bit and 32-bit on the laptop. I went through oracles instructions on installing the drivers but those instructions are standalone, and the laptop looks to not recognize the 64-bit drivers.

Comment: It's been awhile since I installed the Oracle ODBC drivers.  There should be an installer for the 32-bit drivers and a separate installer for the 64-bit drivers.  It should be as simply as installing both of the drivers on the same system, thus allowing 32-bit and 64-bit applications, to use the ODBC drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Install the the 32 and 64 bits of the ODBC driver. One will be installed at `C:\Program Files` and the other at `C:\Program Files(x86)`. Your 32 bits programs (e.g. Excel) must use the 32bit driver, and the 64bit app (e.g. Dbeaver) must use the 64bit version.

Tip: put the driver version in the connection name so you will know when to use each one.